# how to add text widgets to wordpress sidebar using function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add text widget into my site sidebar when I activate theme. How can I do this using wordpress function or other methods? I'm using wordpress 4.1.
 Help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that what kind of widget you want to create, so i give you a simple example so you can understand.

Write blow code in functions.php or create an external file and include it into functions.php

First Register the Widget:

```
//========= Your Custom Widget
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'your_simple_widget' );
function your_simple_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Your_Simple_Same_Widget' );
}
```

Second Create a widget body:

```
class Your_Simple_Same_Widget extends WP_Widget {  }
```

**NOTE:** `register_widget( 'Your_Simple_Same_Widget' );` name and `class Your_Simple_Same_Widget` and widget setup name must be same

There are four parts of widget in class

1. Widget Setup
2. How to display on front end
3. Update Widget values
4. Widget form or fields in admin panel

Ok Third in class Write this code like:

```
//========= Your Custom Widget Body
class Your_Simple_Same_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    //=======> Widget setup
    function Your_Simple_Same_Widget() {
        /* Widget settings. */
    $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'your class', 'description' => __('Your Class Description widget', 'your class') );

        /* Widget control settings. */
    $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'your_widget' );

    /* Create the widget. */
    $this->WP_Widget( 'your_widget', __('Widget Heading', 'your class'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    //=======> How to display the widget on the screen.
    function widget($args, $widgetData) {
        extract($args);

        //=======> Our variables from the widget settings.
        $your_widget_title = $widgetData['txtYourTitle'];
        $your_widget_description = $widgetData['txtYourDescription'];

        //=======> widget body
        echo $before_widget;
        echo '<div class="">';

                if($your_widget_title){
                    echo '<h2>'.$your_widget_title .'</h2>';
                }

        if($your_widget_description){
                    echo '<p>'.$your_widget_description .'</p>';
        }

        echo "</div>";
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    //=======>Update the widget 
    function update($new_widgetData, $old_widgetData) {
        $widgetData = $old_widgetData;

        //Strip tags from title and name to remove HTML 
        $widgetData['txtYourTitle'] = $new_widgetData['txtYourTitle'];
        $widgetData['txtYourDescription'] = $new_widgetData['txtYourDescription'];
        return $widgetData;
    }

    //=======>widget Display
    function form($widgetData) {
        //Set up some default widget settings.
        $widgetData = wp_parse_args((array) $widgetData);
?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('txtYourTitle'); ?>">Widget Title:</label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('txtYourTitle'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('txtYourTitle'); ?>" value="<?php echo $widgetData['txtYourTitle']; ?>" style="width:275px;" />
        </p>
    <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('txtYourDescription'); ?>">Widget Title:</label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('txtYourDescription'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('txtYourDescription'); ?>" value="<?php echo $widgetData['txtYourDescription']; ?>" style="width:275px;" />
        </p>
<?php
    }

}
?>
```

I hope this may help you.